# how to convert std::string pointer to std::string

Tags: c++, pointers

i have std::string pointer and i like to copy its value to ordinary std::string 
i can't find quick and fast way to do it . 
i have this :

```
int main ()
{
   std::string * pStr = new std::string("hello") 
    std::string strNew = pStr->??? // how to convert ?


  return 0;
}
```

Comment: The answer is obvious, and has been given, but it ignores the larger question: why do you have a pointer to an `std::string` in the first place?  You would _never_ `new` an `std::string`, and about the only reason for using a pointer would be as a "maybe" return value, for a function which does some sort of lookup.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways:

```
std::string strNew = pStr->c_str(); // Be careful of `\0` with in the string
```

or

```
std::string strNew = *pStr;
```

The second is better, because  C-style string can not represent std::string correctly. It ends a string at first `\0` and ignores trailing.

Comment: why is the second  better?

Comment: @jgmao: The first one is simply incorrect. It will fail on `std::string("a\0b\0c")`, and it will fail subtly and quietly.

Comment: @jgmao: Because c-style string can not represent `std::string` correctly. It ends a string at first `\0` and ignores trailing.

Answer (score 6):

Dereference:

```
std::string strNew = *pStr;
```

Comment: And to make it clear it is a constructor, not an assignemnt: `std::string strNew(*pStr);`

Comment: @VincenzoPii: Quite, though the same works for assignment of an existing string.